# Small Firebase node worker to pass userid

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm developing an application where an administrator can create a client account, which will then have read only access to the resources created by the admin.

My security rule is defined as follows:

```
{
  "rules":{
    ".write":"false",
    ".read":"false",
    "users": {
      ".write":"false",
      ".read":"false",
      "$userid": {
        ".write":"false",
        ".read":"($userid===auth.uid||root.child('clients').hasChild('auth.uid'))"
...
...
}
```

I want the client to then access the resource via `myfirebase.firebaseio.com/users/$adminUID/...`

where `$adminUID` is the user id of the admin account, where the resources are stored.

Adding the newly created user's id into  `/users/$adminUID/clients` seems fairly straight forward since the firebase SDK will return you the UID of any new user you created.

But I'm working with iOS and OS X so there is no way for me to pass in parameters for the user I'm creating. That led me to look into how to setup a small `Node js` worker that would listen for a newly created user and then set a `path` property (which would be the admin's userID).

But at the moment I'm struggling to figure out how to implement that.

I tried to setup a quick node script with:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ref = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/');

ref.child('users/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

and then run it with `node worker.js` but it doesn't return me anything in the log.

**EDIT**
Added excerpt from rules.yaml

```
access:
  - location: /users/$userid/
    read: $userid === auth.uid
  - location: users/$userid/organisation/info
    write: ($userid === auth.uid) && (createOnly() || updateOnly())
  - location: users/$userid/slides/
    write: ($userid === auth.uid)
  - location: users/$userid/general/
    write: ($userid === auth.uid)
  - location: users/$userid/data
    write: ($userid === auth.uid)
  - location: /users/$userid
    read: root.clients.hasChild('auth.uid')
```

Comment: Why can't you pass in parameters for the user you are creating? Once you are auth'd you can create users, delete them, add data to nodes freely. In our app, when we create the user, we create the Firebase user, map that to a user in the user node and add a bunch of data about the user in that node (name, address, etc)

Comment: @Jay that is true, but that would mean logging my admin user out first

Comment: This reads like a puzzle. Are `$userid` and `$adminUID` different? Where is the `clients` object located? It'd be very help to see your entire schema.

Comment: @AnidMonsur you're right. I tried to clarify a bit. Don't know if this makes more sense?

Comment: Is your admin an actual admin in that they can read/write to any path? I'm confused because none of your rules allow any writing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I can see that's confusing, once you go a level deeper you get write access. I've added the rules I've written in yaml (using the blaze compiler)

Comment: As a followup, your initial sentence states that you want an admin to create a client account and that client will read-only access to the resources created by the admin. The coding part aside, what is preventing the admin user from creating a client account (create the user in FB, add the user info to a /users node add some data to a /data node) thereby allowing the client to log in and access said data? Why do you have to log the admin user out first?